# Calculate time energy is stored in capacitor

Tags: capacitor, energy, time

I have this problem: [image]

I've calculated A) to be 8 nJ, and my Vc(0) = 4 V and Vc(∞) = 0 V. I tried using the wc(t) = 1/2CVc^2 formula to calculate the time when the energy of the capacitor is 1 nJ. However I failed. How should I think when trying to calculate the time?

Comment: So you calculated the voltage when the cap has 1nJ of energy?  Do you know how to write the equation for v(t) for an RC circuit?  Set that equation to the voltage you calculated and solve for t.

Comment: @JohnD Hi, the voltage I got was 1.41421 V (0.000000001 = 1/2(0.000000001)Vc^2. After that I used the formula Vc(t) = V(∞)+[V(0)+V(∞)]e^-t/RC. I put 1.41421 = 4e^-t/10us and got the t = 10 us. However I'm a not completaly certain if I used the Vc(t) formula correctly.

Comment: @Vetenskap I think you are correct with your t=10.4us